# Yosemite and Lake Tahoe Road Trip Assistance

Tags: road-trips, camping, yosemite

I'm starting to plan a road trip that will take place in late August of this year.  I'm looking for any guidance or recommendations for places to stay in both Yosemite and in Lake Tahoe.  For Yosemite, we are ideally trying to find places that offer "glamping" (places that will provide the equipment for camping so you're not required to bring it and sometimes can be a bit nicer then your average camp site).  Any locations that would include meals would be great but are not required.

Answer (score 3):

I just stayed in the [Camp Curry](http://www.yosemitepark.com/curry-village.aspx) tents at Yosemite. I believe this is what you want. Note, it's crowded. You will not feel away from everything, unless and until you hike into the back country.